# Trying to find repeated names in a database

Tags: python, pandas

[Database at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjGHe.png)

I have this database at hand and i want to mess around with it trying to learn what i can.
I'm trying to see if names in the "EmployeeName" column has the names that have been around for at least 3 years so i can see how their pay increased or decreased in those years.

df3.duplicated(subset=['EmployeeName'])

i have tried this but issue with this is that the first resulst will always come out False since they didnt get "repeated" yet so it counts that as a False for their first instance but sees that the name got repeated later down the database then says True but some of the names really has no duplicates.

So how can i find out who really gets repeated and how can i take out the non repeated ones.
I'm new to this,just got this database from Kaggle and trying to see which jobs got better or worse throught the years then try and visualize it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE COUNT(EmployeeName) > 1 ORDER BY Year;
```

Comment: Yea that would have been great but i dont know how to do that in pandas.